# A bound on an integral

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Consider $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ where $f(z)$ is a polynomial such that $f(z)=0$
and $g(z)$ is an analytic function. I want to find the tightest bound the following integral:
$\int_0^1 f(z)g(z) dz$

I know $f(z)$ and then
$\int_0^1 f(z) dz$ and also I know $\int_0^1 g(z)dz$ but I don't know what is g(z).

Thanks to the comment: $f(z),g(z)\geq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can say absolutely nothing about $\int_0^1 f(z)g(z)\,dz$ given your information.

Take for example $f(z) = z$ and $g(z) = C\cdot \sin(2\pi z)$. Then $\int_0^1 g(z)\,dz = 0$ for all choices of $C$, but $\int_0^1 f(z)g(z)\,dz = -\frac{C}{2\pi}$